# Azure web app Node.js returns 404 after deployment

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, nuxt.js, devops, github-actions

I've been stuck with this problem for the last couple of days. I'm trying to deploy a nuxt app with server side rendering to an azure web app but when the deployment finishes the app returns a 404.

Here is my github actions script:

```yaml
name: Build and deploy Node.js app to Azure Web App - mercado-digital-staging

on:
  push:
    branches:
      - master
  workflow_dispatch:

jobs:
  build:
    runs-on: windows-latest

    steps:
    - uses: actions/checkout@v2

    - name: Set up Node.js version
      uses: actions/setup-node@v1
      with:
        node-version: '14.x'

    - name: npm install, build, and test
      run: |
        npm install
        npm run build --if-present
        npm run test --if-present

    - name: copy files
      run: |
        mkdir server
        mkdir server\.nuxt
        mkdir server\static
        Copy-Item -Path .\.nuxt\* -Destination .\server\.nuxt -Recurse -Force
        Copy-Item -Path .\static\* -Destination .\server\static -Recurse -Force
        Copy-Item -Path .\nuxt.config.js -Destination .\server -Force
        Copy-Item -Path .\package.json -Destination .\server -Force
        Copy-Item -Path .\package-lock.json -Destination .\server -Force
        Move-Item -Path .\static\web.config -Destination .\server\ -Force

    - name: Upload artifact for deployment job
      uses: actions/upload-artifact@v2
      with:
        name: node-app
        path: .\server

  deploy:
    runs-on: windows-latest
    needs: build
    environment:
      name: 'production'
      url: ${{ steps.deploy-to-webapp.outputs.webapp-url }}

    steps:
    - name: Download artifact from build job
      uses: actions/download-artifact@v2
      with:
        name: node-app

    - name: npm install
      run: |
        npm uninstall nuxt
        npm install nuxt-start
        npm i --production

    - name: 'Deploy to Azure Web App'
      id: deploy-to-webapp
      uses: azure/webapps-deploy@v2
      with:
        app-name: 'mercado-digital-staging'
        slot-name: 'production'
        publish-profile: ${{ secrets.AzureAppService_PublishProfile_eb3443a52796493d9744aa0c55879c5b }}
        package: .\
```

My wwwroot in the web app:

[image: wwwroot]

The web.confg

```xml
<configuration>
  <system.webServer>
    <!-- Visit https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/introduction-to-websockets-on-windows-azure-web-sites/ for more information on WebSocket support -->
    <webSocket enabled="false" />
    <handlers>
      <!-- Indicates that the server.js file is a Node.js site to be handled by the iisnode module -->
      <add name="iisnode" path=".nuxt/server" verb="*" modules="iisnode"/>
    </handlers>
    <rewrite>
      <rules>
        <!-- Do not interfere with requests for node-inspector debugging -->
        <rule name="NodeInspector" patternSyntax="ECMAScript" stopProcessing="true">
          <match url="^server\/debug[\/]?" />
        </rule>

        <!-- First we consider whether the incoming URL matches a physical file in the /public folder -->
        <rule name="StaticContent">
          <action type="Rewrite" url="public{REQUEST_URI}"/>
        </rule>

        <!-- All other URLs are mapped to the Node.js site entry point -->
        <rule name="DynamicContent">
          <conditions>
            <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="True"/>
          </conditions>
          <action type="Rewrite" url="server"/>
        </rule>
      </rules>
    </rewrite>

    <!-- 'bin' directory has no special meaning in Node.js and apps can be placed in it -->
    <security>
      <requestFiltering>
        <hiddenSegments>
          <remove segment="bin"/>
        </hiddenSegments>
      </requestFiltering>
    </security>

    <!-- Make sure error responses are left untouched -->
    <httpErrors existingResponse="PassThrough" />
    <iisnode nodeProcessCommandLine="npm start" watchedFiles="web.config;*.js" debuggingEnabled="false" />
    <!--
      You can control how Node is hosted within IIS using the following options:
        * watchedFiles: semi-colon separated list of files that will be watched for changes to restart the server
        * node_env: will be propagated to node as NODE_ENV environment variable
        * debuggingEnabled - controls whether the built-in debugger is enabled

      See https://github.com/tjanczuk/iisnode/blob/master/src/samples/configuration/web.config for a full list of options
    -->
    <!--<iisnode watchedFiles="web.config;*.js"/>-->
    <staticContent><mimeMap fileExtension=".json" mimeType="application/json" /></staticContent>
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

package.json

```json
{
  "name": "mercado-digital",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "nuxt",
    "build": "nuxt build",
    "start": "nuxt-start",
    "generate": "nuxt generate",
    "lint:js": "eslint --ext \".js,.vue\" --ignore-path .gitignore .",
    "lint": "npm run lint:js"
  },
  "engines": {
    "node": ">=8.17",
    "npm": ">=6.13.4"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@nuxtjs/axios": "^5.13.1",
    "@nuxtjs/vuetify": "^1.11.3",
    "core-js": "^3.9.1",
    "nuxt-start": "^2.15.7",
    "oidc-client": "^1.11.5"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@nuxt/types": "^2.15.3",
    "@nuxt/typescript-build": "^2.1.0",
    "@nuxtjs/device": "^2.1.0",
    "@nuxtjs/eslint-config-typescript": "^6.0.0",
    "@nuxtjs/eslint-module": "^3.0.2",
    "babel-eslint": "^10.1.0",
    "eslint": "^7.22.0",
    "eslint-plugin-nuxt": "^2.0.0",
    "eslint-plugin-vue": "^7.7.0"
  }
}
```

Appsettings:
WEBSITE_NODE_DEFAULT_VERSION: ~14

The url of the app:
https://mercado-digital-staging.azurewebsites.net/

Is there a way to debug this or too get the startup logs? If you need anything else please let me know. Thanks for the help in advance!

Comment: Did you looked into this one? https://nuxtjs.org/docs/2.x/deployment/deployment-azure-portal

Comment: Yes sir, I added the host and the env appsettings and found no success @kissu

Comment: You don't have any logs during the build or the runtime somewhere?

Answer (score 0):

I think below is wrong.

```
"start": "nuxt-start",
```

It should be

```
"start": "nuxt start",
```

In addition, your web.config file, I look a little strange, I am not sure whether it can run normally. If you can, that's the best. If it doesn't work, you can refer to the web.config file format that works normally before and make adjustments.

[You can download my `web.config` from github.](https://github.com/Jason446620/dotenv-azuredemo/blob/master/web.config)

[image]